# How to get all Media attachments (excluding uncategorised) In WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get all media attachment which are put under some category it should be `order by id ASC`. I don't want to pull the uncategorised media attachments.

I want following information about the media attachment:

- Media Url,
- Media Description,
- Category Name of the media,
- Category
- Slug of the Category

Any body there to help me out to solve my problem?

Comment: Anybody there to help me to solve my problem?

Comment: So you have added categories to your media attachments? or to the post/pages?

Comment: Yes i have already added categories to some media attachments which i want to pull now. Its only to media attachments not to any post or pages.

Comment: You can find the loop example here http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/advanced-use-of-attachments-in-wordpress-creating-a-featured-image-for-a-category--wp-35203

Comment: I've already gone through the article from where I've a got idea to add category to the attachment. And i've included the same in my functions.php. But the query is not clear to me. Can you help me to elaborate with sample code? 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', is clear to me. How to add 'exclude' => 1; 'exclude_tree' =>1; and where? how to get category name and slug from the result. These are my quarries.

Comment: Waiting to hear from anybody...

Comment: What have you tried? We can't give you the code if you haven't tried anything...

Comment: Well what I have tried is to get names and slugs of categories of media attachment excluding categorized is below:
<?php $args = array( 'orderby' => 'id',  'hide_empty'=> 0,   'exclude' => 1,   'exclude_tree' =>  1,    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
                  <li><a data-filter=".<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
   <?php } ?>

Comment: And below code is fetching all media attachment urls:
 <?php
  $query_images_args = array(
      'post_type'      => 'attachment',
      'tax_query' => array( 'taxonomy' => 'category',  'exclude' => 1,   'exclude_tree' =>  1  ),
      'post_mime_type' => 'image',
      'post_status'    => 'inherit',
      'posts_per_page' => - 1,
      'order' => 'ASC',
  );
  
  $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
  
  $images = array();
  foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
      $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
  }
  
  print_r($images);
 ?>

Comment: I want to fetch all media attachment urls, category name and slug excluding medias having category categorized.

Comment: I just found this code:

<?php
$args = array(    'post_type' => 'attachment',    'numberposts' => -1,    'post_status' => null,    'post_parent' => null, // any parent    ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
       the_title();        the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);        the_excerpt();
    }
}

?>

Which giving me the media (display) and its title, now only I want now the category name and slug. Also want to restrict uncategorised images.

Comment: I have solved is a bit but unable to filter "uncategorised" media. Also unable to assign the category to li class.
`<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'attachment','numberposts' => -1,'post_status' => null,  'post_parent' => null, ); $attachments = get_posts($args); if ($attachments) { foreach ($attachments as $post) {setup_postdata($post);?><li class='element <?php echo the_category($post->ID);?>'><div class="portfolio-image"><a href="#"><?php  echo'<img  class="attachment-portfolio-four wp-post-image"  src="'.the_attachment_link($post->ID, false).'" >'; ?></a></div></li>
<?php } } ?>`

Comment: Try this `$args = array(       
         'post_type' => 'attachment',
         'post_status' => 'inherit',
         'category__not_in' 
    => array(2) //id for category
     );`

Comment: I want to exclude category ID 1 which is for "uncategorised". I have given below query but getting only 5 images. 
`$args = array(  'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit',  'category_not_in' => array(1),  );`

I have tried with `'post_status' => 'inherit',` and `'numberposts' => -1,` its giving all the images. `'category_not_in' => array(1),` actually not working.

Kindly help me out here.

Comment: Where did you get `numberposts` from? It should be `posts_per_page`

Comment: Well I want to fetch images from media library. Category assigned to uploaded media. Its not necessary that i'll pull images which are attached to any post or page. `numberposts` i got from any article while googling. My main problem is `category_not_in` not working also i am not able to assign the category name received to `<li class="<?php the_category($post->ID);?>"><img src="<?php the_attachment_link($post->ID, false); ?>" </li>`.

Comment: Please check the link for which i am trying to write the code : [http://koncept.org.in/work/](http://koncept.org.in/work/)

Comment: I have managed to remove link from category received but still searching to filter uncategorised from query. Pls help.

Comment: Still waiting for help regarding fetching only media which is associated with any category...